# Dynamic load c dll in C#

Tags: c#, c, windows

I have a c dll, and want to dynamic load it by C#. I do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Dota2Plugins
{
    class Interop
    {
        #region Win API
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public extern static IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hLib, string lpProcName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public extern static bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hLib);
        #endregion

        private IntPtr hLib;

        public Interop(String DLLPath)
        {
            hLib = LoadLibrary(DLLPath);
            if (hLib == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("not found dll : " + DLLPath);
            }
        }

        ~Interop()
        {
            FreeLibrary(hLib);
        }

        public IntPtr GetIntPtr(string APIName)
        {
            IntPtr api = GetProcAddress(hLib, APIName);
            if (api == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("not found api : " + APIName);
            }

            return api;
        }

        public Delegate GetDelegate(string APIName, Type t)
        {
            IntPtr api = GetIntPtr(APIName);
            return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(api, t);
        }

    }
}
```

Loding dll like this :

> Interop interop = new Interop("KeyBoardHook.dll");`

but when I run my application, it throw the error :

> not found dll : KeyBoardHook.dll

I have copied the dll to the application directory.

I used the relativity dir and absolute dir to try it and get the same error result.

How can I dynamic load a c DLL in C# and call the DLL export api ?

Comment: `application directory`, is this where the exe is?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Is there a particular reason why you do not want to use `DllImport` with your dll?

Comment: yeah, I'm sure the dll file directory is correct. I have resolved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, I'm sure the dll file directory is correct. I have resolved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two questions, first, the DLL not found, and how you can make dynamic load from C.

- Have you made sure you are compiling the project in the same architecture as the DLL?

This is a common problem, when trying to load an X64 dll from a C# 32bit project.

- Have you tried File.Exists at the beggining of the constructor `public Interop(String DLLPath)`?

Perhaps your Application Directory is not correct as mentioned by Stefan in the comments.

Try the full path as well.

---

About the dynamic loading, this is another topic. You must specify the parameters in DLL, you could theoretically do them in run-time.

If you have the headers, you could make a class derived from `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject` and parse the header in run-time, overriding from `TryInvokeMember` (and once you get it, you can parse it).

I wouldn't use this method though.

I'm not sure how you'd do it dynamically without the headers, I'm afraid.

Comment: I use a C#64bit project and X64 c dll, and then Load the dll succeed, Thakns!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your declarations are wrong, as far I can tell you should have:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

I am taking these from http://pinvoke.net.

The issue you are facing is likely due to the fact that C# will marshal the `string` as `BStr` (length prefixed string) by default ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings)), but `LoadLibrary` will resolve to [`LoadLibraryA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) that expects a null terminated ansi string (`LPStr`).

You might also be interested in Vanara.PInvoke.Kernel32 ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vanara.PInvoke.Kernel32), [Repository](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara)) that together with its companion libraries has all the Windows API definitions you may likely need.

Comment: thanks, this is not the reason why program can't load dll. But it is the resolution to find the dll function entry. Thanks a lot !